# How do I calculate the medial axis for a 2D vector shape?

Tags: python, svg, medial-axis

I have a 2D shape stored as a path element in an SVG. The shapes consist of Bezier curves and line segments.

I also have a set of equally space points along the shape that I am generating 
using arc length parameterization.

How can I use either the SVG or these points to determine the medial axis of the shape?

I am using Python, but any sort of pseudocode or algorithm advice would be much appreciated.

---

The following is an example of the types of shapes I am dealing with, and the red dots are my sampled points along the curve.

[image: example]

Comment: You you provide an example shape for us to play with?

Comment: Sure, here is the one used in the example above: http://hastebin.com/esiyojehik.svg
And here is the set of points along this shape: http://hastebin.com/usosaruyup.py

Comment: What do you exactly mean with medial axis? I mean are you referring to the classic major inertia axis (http://www.mukimuki.fr/flashblog/2009/05/20/magic-moments/) or to a curved line that stais in the center of the shape all along it trying to follow its borders eventually curved nature?

Comment: I am nearly finished with exactly such a [project](https://github.com/FlorisSteenkamp/MAT) on github. You can already check out the [demo](http://mat-demo.appspot.com). I will post a complete answer as soon as the project is done.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A tad late but here goes:

[image: Medial and Scale Axis Transform]
[image: Scale Axis Transform]
[image: Medial Axis Transform]
[image: 2-Prong]
[image: 3-Prong]

The pictures above shows: (I've converted the OP's image to SVG with an online tool 
hence the ragged boundary that is an artifact of the red dots)
1. Superimposed Medial and Scale Axis Transform (*MAT* and *SAT*).
2. Scale Axis Transform only.
3. Medial Axis Transform only.
4. One of many *2-prongs* (see below).
5. The single *3-prong* in the *SAT* (there are many in the *MAT*).

To find the *Medial Axis (MA)* or *Medial Axis Transform (MAT)* (purple curves in above image) the following algorithm
can be used (based on a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/70ae/5b583303af0b4d60d356d08f8ed84e1babbc.pdf) 
by Choi, Choi, Moon and Wee - see a demo implementation [here](http://mat-demo.appspot.com/#!/test-mat) that 
also handles intersecting shapes and shapes with holes). Other algorithms also exist.

The algorithm is much harder to implement than finding a binary image (e.g. bitmap) skeleton 
(a.k.a. grassfire or discrete transform) but has several advantages (such as being analytic). 
To simplify things, the discussion below only handles the case of simple 
(non-intersecting) shapes without holes.

### Some definitions

- *Curve* - A parametric bezier curve with parameter *t* ∈ [0,1]. In other words,
  a typical curve as used in vector graphics.
- *Shape (Ω)* - (Definition taken directly from the paper) - "the closure of a connected 
  bounded open subset in ℝ² bounded by a finite number of mutually disjoint 
  simple closed *curves*." For the purposes of this answer it can be further assumed
  that the *shape* has no holes. In simple terms it is the area enclosed by the
  boundary given by a number of *curves* - the filled gray part in the image above.
- *Boundary* - The boundary of the *shape*. In other words, an indexed sequence of *curves* 
  such that the starting point of any curve at *t*=0 corresponds to the previous 
  curve's endpoint at *t*=1. The *boundary* is assumed positively oriented 
  (i.e. by walking along the boundary in an anti-clockwise direction the shape 
  will always be to your left).
- *Boundary point* - Any point on the shape boundary fully identified by an 
  index identifying the *curve* and a *t* *curve* paramter.
- *Maximal disk* - Disks within the *shape* not occluded by any other disk 
  also within the shape. Every *maximal disk* can be identified
  by 1 or more (usually 2) *boundary point*s and its center point.
- *n-prong* - A *maximal disk* touching the shape boundary tangentially at n
  points.
- *Branch point* - An *n-prong* *maximal disk center* with n >= 3. In other words
  a point on the *MA* that forms a vertex in the *MA* planar tree.
- *Medial Axis (MA)* - The union of the centers of all *n-prongs*.
- *Medial Axis Transform (MAT)* - The union of all *n-prongs*. In other words,
  the radius of the *maximal disks* are included in the definition.
- *Contact point (cp)* - A *boundary point* linked to a unique *maximal disk*
  that has already been found.
- *Sharp corner* - A *boundary point*, usually at curve parameter *t* = 0 or 
  *t* = 1, that is not differentiable (not smooth) and that forms an interior 
  angle < 180°.
- *Dull corner* - Same as a sharp corner except the angle > 180°.
- *Cp graph* - A graph (not necessarily planar) with vertices being 
  *contact point*s thus also containing information regarding all found
  *maximal disk*s and in turn the entire *MAT*. Each vertex (*cp*) in the graph
  has the following edges:

  - *next* - The first *contact point* found from the current one by walking
    anti-clockwise around the *boundary*.
  - *prev*  - The first *contact point* found from the current one by walking
    clockwise around the *boundary*.
  - *next-around* - The first *contact point* found by going around the
    *maximal disk* in an anti-clockwise direction.
  - *prev-around* - The first *contact point* found by going around the
    *maximal disk* in a clockwise direction.
    We can view each of the above as an operator (.) on a *contact point* returning
    another *contact point* by following an edge, e.g. if *a* is a *contact point*,
    then *a*.*next* is another *contact point*.

### Some notes

- The *Medial Axis Transform* forms an unrooted planar tree with tree leaves at 
  every *1-prong* center (including *sharp corner*s); if the shape has holes 
  then the *MAT* is a planar graph.
- You can remove noise on the shape boundary by applying a 
  *Scale Axis Transform (SAT)* (red curves in above image) to the *MAT*. The
  [demo](http://mat-demo.appspot.com/#!/test-mat) implements such a transform, 
  based on [this](http://www.balintmiklos.com/scale-axis/theory_socg_2009.html)
  research. However, the demo improves the algorithm by ensuring the *SAT* is a subset
  of the *MAT* and guarantees topology preservation.

### Algorithm overview

1. Find all *1-prongs*; they are exactly the *Medial Axis* tree leaves. These
   are the *sharp corners* and the *1-prongs* touching a *boundary point* with 
   maximum local inward curvature. Add the *contact point*s of the *1-prongs* to the *cp-graph*. 
   Note that since *1-prong*s have one *contact point* only, the edges *next-around*
   and *prev-around* will just return the found *contact point* again.
2. For a representative set of *boundary point*s  (such as those red dots given by the OP), 
   calculate their *maximal disk*s. They will generally be *2-prongs*. (See 'finding a 2-prong' below).
   Add their *contact point*s to the *cp-graph* by connecting the appropriate edges. Note
   that in this case, since we found *2-prongs*, if *next-around* 
   (or *prev-around*) is followed twice one will be back at the same *contact point*.
3. Finally find the *n-prongs* for n >= 3. Starting from each *contact point*:

   1. traverse the *cp-graph* by starting with a *contact point* (say **cp1**) and 
      applying **cp1**.*next*.*next-around* repeatedly until you are back at 
      **cp1**.
   2. If either 1 or 2 iterations of the above occured move to the next *contact point*
      on the *boundary* (using *next*). If, however, 3 or more iterations were required, 
      it can be proved that a *3-prong* *branch point* exists
      and should be inserted with *contact point*s on each *boundary* piece between
      **cp1** and **cp1**.*next*.

      In that case, insert the *3-prong* (see below on how to find these) and go back
      to step 1, again starting from **cp1**.
   3. Repeat step 1 and 2 until all *3-prongs* have been found.
4. The structure of the *MAT* has now been found implicitly.
   To extract the *MAT* one needs to traverse the *cp-graph*. Choose any
   *contact point* (call it **cp1**) as the root (for simplicity let's assume it to be linked to a *2-prong*), 
   and apply *next* (call it **cp2**). A line can now be drawn from *cp1*'s linked *maximal disk*
   center to that of **cp2**. This line is an approximation of a subset of the *MA*. 
   A much better approximation is obtained via interpolation between the points
   since we know the boundary tangents at the *contact points*. Let the two line 
   endpoints be the endpoints of a quadratic bezier curve. Since the orientation of the *MA* at the
   two *maximal disk* centers are known exactly (via the average of the 2 boundary tangents) we have
   the derivatives of the quadratic beziers at the endpoints too and we can construct
   a best approximation qudratic bezier curve between the points. 
   If **cp2** is linked to a *3-prong* it implies that the planar tree formed
   by the *MA* bifurcates (i.e. branches ot forks) and we need to follow both *MA* 
   edges (by using, for example, a stack or recursion). If, on the other hand, 
   **cp2** is linked to a *1-prong* a leaf of the *MA* has been reached and the 
   traversal stops for that edge. In fact, since the *MA* forms a 
   planar tree the traversal algorithm is essentialy the same as that of any other 
   tree data structure.

### Finding a 2-prong

1. I will summarize here but the paper by Choi et al. explains this part quite
   clearly and is easy to follow.

   Choose a point on the *boundary* that will be the first *contact point* of 
   our *2-prong* and call it **bp1**.  Draw an inward normal ray form the 
   *boundary point* (i.e the first 'prong' of the *2-prong* to be found). Now iterate:

   1. Select a point, **p1**, (at a distance **d1** from **bp1** along 
      this ray) with **d1** large enough such that a circle (drawn tangentially at **bp1** 
      with center on the ray) will cut the *boundary* in at least one more point.
   2. Find the closest *boundary point* to **p1**, call it **bp2**. Finally, find
      the point on the ray equidistant from **bp1** and **bp2** and call it **p2**.
   3. Go back to step 2 with **p2** the new **p1**.
   4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the distance from **p1** to the two 
      *boundary point*s are equal to within some tolerance. The *2-prong* has
      now been found with **bp1** and **bp2** its two *contact point*s and
      **p1** its center.

### Finding a 3-prong

Here we deviate a bit from the paper by constructing a circumcircle as opposed to
using a potential function.

1. Select the *boundary point*'s (**cp1**'s) linked *maximal disk* center as an initial guess to the
   *3-prong* center to be found. Call it **p**.
2. Find the 3 closest points to **p** seperately to each of the 3+ *boundary piece*s.
3. Construct the circumcircle of those points and use its center as the new 
   point **p**.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the distance to the 3 boundary pieces from **p**
   is equal to within some tolerance.
5. Mark the 3 *boundary points* thus found as *contact points* of the 3-prong.
   The point **p** is the center of the *3-prong*.

Please feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: I am no longer working on this project, but thank you for such a thorough and clear answer. I enjoyed reading it!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Do you know the computational complexity of this algorithm?  And, are there any additional simplifications that can be made if all boundary segments are linear?

Comment: The algorithm has an average run-time complexity of (for a specified accuracy) O(n log n) and a worst case of O(n^2), where n is the number of beziers. This is a great simplification though as it also depends on the bitlength of the input beziers, etc. Yes, if all boundary segments are linear the algorithm is much, much simpler and if I recall correctly there is a known O(n log n) average case algorithm for that.

Comment: Is it easy to make the algorithm return a discrete set of maximal balls?  As far as I understand, in its current form, the paths of the MAT are returned, so the position of maximal balls can all be computed from them.  But how do I get the diameter of each ball?  Great library BTW, still trying to understand the paper!

Comment: @fweth Thanks :) Yes, it returns the maximal balls as part of the MAT. The MA (Medial Axis) is the path at the 'center' of the shape. The MAT (Medial Axis Transform) is the path PLUS a ball radius at each point of the path (that contains all info to reconstruct the original shape). For example within the library when iterating the path (see e.g. lines 69-83 at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xuruhe?file=src%2Fget-thinned-path.ts), points on the path are returned as a `CpNode` object. This object contains a `cp` property that has, ...(continued)

Comment: ... in turn, a `circle` property which is exactly what you're looking for. It actually stores additional (technically mathematically redundant info) such as the points on the boundary that tangentially intersects the maximal balls, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can see the code from skimage (scikit-image). you will find the code for skeletonization and also for medial-axis (skimage.morphology.medial_axis)

The source are available at this address : https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/v0.12.2/skimage/morphology/_skeletonize.py#L103

This algorithm computes the medial axis transform of an image
    as the ridges of its distance transform.

The different steps of the algorithm are as follows

```
A lookup table is used, that assigns 0 or 1 to each configuration of
   the 3x3 binary square, whether the central pixel should be removed
   or kept. 

We want a point to be removed if it has more than one neighbor
   and if removing it does not change the number of connected components.


The distance transform to the background is computed, as well as
   the cornerness of the pixel.

The foreground (value of 1) points are ordered by
   the distance transform, then the cornerness.

A cython function is called to reduce the image to its skeleton. It
   processes pixels in the order determined at the previous step, and
   removes or maintains a pixel according to the lookup table. 

Because
   of the ordering, it is possible to process all pixels in only one
   pass.
```

I hope it will help you